# Can someone help me identify this fixture?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, valve, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to find out what fixtures to purchase for this valve ?
I found some numbers on these, but even googling them the entire day did not result in anything fruitful. Hoping if someone knows which model /make is compatible with this ?
Lots of pics here:
[image: Valve Backside][image: Valve cartridge]

If you think this is Moen, can I just put in any moen cartridge and we're good to go ? Can you point me to the one available on amazon that can be installed ?
[More pictures of the cartridge here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnwNsHXxIuCYguBDJ27UtgD2Rlvbjw?e=TjM1Uh)

Comment: A couple more photos and even the numbers you found may be helpful , the back of the valve would also help here.

Comment: That black plastic part should screw off, remove it and add another pic please; we need to see more of the valve stem area. I believe it is **Moen** by initial look at the end of the stem, but another pic would help confirm...

Comment: Do you have any of the old trim? If so, include those in your pic.